# Bundle getArguments() null

Tags: android, arguments, fragment, bundle

I'm trying to send data from one fragment to another fragment.

When I try to get the arguments, these are null. I do this in onCreateView method.

First fragment code:

```
    Inspecciones_fragment inf = new Inspecciones_fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("tipo_inspecciones_activity", tag);
    inf.setArguments(bundle);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, new Inspecciones_fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Second fragment code:

```
    Bundle extras = getArguments();

    if(extras != null){
    int tagInspeccion = extras.getInt("tipo_inspecciones_activity");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your fragment, where you set arguments,  in operation:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, inf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, new Inspecciones_fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

in the line above you are passing a new instance of your fragment that doesn't contain the bundle. It should be

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, inf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```